# GNU C - Signals never arrive to the handler

Tags: application-development, c

I'm working on a university project which needs to be written in GNU C and run on Ubuntu server. My primary OS at home is Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. The project is about multi thread programming and I always stuck when I need to send a signal from the child process to the parent.

I've used the **strace** to investigate the signal sending and I've found that or the signals are not sent, or these have not arrived to the handler. Finally I've written the most simpler singal handler application for testing reason.

**Here is the code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // DateTime kezeles
#include <fcntl.h> // Rendszerhivasok file
#include <unistd.h> // fork
#include <sys/types.h> // pid_t típus
#include <sys/wait.h> // wait, waitpid
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void HandlerParent(int signalNumber){
    printf("Parent received signal: %d\n", signalNumber);
}

int main (void)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, HandlerParent);
    signal(SIGUSR2, HandlerParent);

    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    sleep(3);
    return 0;
}
```

So again, this is not the project code. I've kicked it out on my PC and it's finished without reaching the handler. I've uploaded to the server of the university and running fine. Let me attach the 2 stacktraces:

**Result on My PC**

```
user@userPC:~/fold/fold1/test$ ./ownkill
```

No any result text... strace:

```
user@userPC:~/fold/fold1/test$ strace -Ff -tt ./ownkill
20:22:46.939854 execve("./ownkill", ["./ownkill"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
20:22:46.940705 brk(0)                  = 0xe2e000
20:22:46.941014 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20:22:46.941220 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa16ba7b000
20:22:46.941499 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20:22:46.941622 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20:22:46.941921 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=145965, ...}) = 0
20:22:46.942198 mmap(NULL, 145965, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa16ba57000
20:22:46.942324 close(3)                = 0
20:22:46.942397 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20:22:46.942515 open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20:22:46.942664 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20:22:46.942749 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
20:22:46.942818 mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa16b495000
20:22:46.942883 mprotect(0x7fa16b650000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20:22:46.942948 mmap(0x7fa16b850000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7fa16b850000
20:22:46.943025 mmap(0x7fa16b856000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa16b856000
20:22:46.943097 close(3)                = 0
20:22:46.943167 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa16ba56000
20:22:46.943234 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa16ba54000
20:22:46.943303 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa16ba54740) = 0
20:22:46.943509 mprotect(0x7fa16b850000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
20:22:46.943582 mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20:22:46.943654 mprotect(0x7fa16ba7d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20:22:46.943715 munmap(0x7fa16ba57000, 145965) = 0
20:22:46.943816 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x40064d, [USR1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa16b4cbc30}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:22:46.943895 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x40064d, [USR2], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa16b4cbc30}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:22:46.943966 getpid()                = 15023
20:22:46.944022 kill(15023, SIGUSR1)    = 0
20:22:46.944082 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [USR1], 8) = 0
20:22:46.944148 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:22:46.944208 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [USR1], NULL, 8) = 0
20:22:46.944267 nanosleep({3, 0}, 0x7fff71e310f0) = 0
20:22:49.944652 exit_group(0)           = ?
20:22:49.944888 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

**Result on the server**

```
USER@SERVER:~/fold/fold1> ./ownkill 
Parent received signal: 10
```

The signal worked well... strace:

```
USER@SERVER:~/fold/fold1> strace -Ff -tt ./ownkill
20:13:21.027730 execve("./ownkill", ["./ownkill"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
20:13:21.031375 brk(0)                  = 0x602000
20:13:21.033631 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2d50000
20:13:21.035918 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20:13:21.038207 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
20:13:21.040400 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=200673, ...}) = 0
20:13:21.042700 mmap(NULL, 200673, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feec2d1f000
20:13:21.044877 close(3)                = 0
20:13:21.047067 open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
20:13:21.049276 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\354\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20:13:21.051473 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1661454, ...}) = 0
20:13:21.053668 mmap(NULL, 3528776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feec27d5000
20:13:21.055848 fadvise64(3, 0, 3528776, POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED) = 0
20:13:21.058040 mprotect(0x7feec2929000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20:13:21.060232 mmap(0x7feec2b29000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x154000) = 0x7feec2b29000
20:13:21.062417 mmap(0x7feec2b2e000, 18504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2b2e000
20:13:21.064619 close(3)                = 0
20:13:21.066834 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2d1e000
20:13:21.069021 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2d1d000
20:13:21.071213 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2d1c000
20:13:21.073461 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7feec2d1d700) = 0
20:13:21.075774 mprotect(0x7feec2b29000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
20:13:21.077954 mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20:13:21.080143 mprotect(0x7feec2d51000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20:13:21.082318 munmap(0x7feec2d1f000, 200673) = 0
20:13:21.084716 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x40064d, [USR1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7feec28079e0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:13:21.086917 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x40064d, [USR2], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7feec28079e0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:13:21.089118 getpid()                = 16382
20:13:21.091313 kill(16382, SIGUSR1)    = 0
20:13:21.092463 --- SIGUSR1 (User defined signal 1) @ 0 (0) ---
20:13:21.094575 fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
20:13:21.096769 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feec2d4f000
20:13:21.098964 write(1, "Parent received signal: 10\n", 27Parent received signal: 10) = 27
20:13:21.101292 rt_sigreturn(0x1)       = 0
20:13:21.103473 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
20:13:21.105654 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
20:13:21.107841 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
20:13:21.110018 nanosleep({3, 0}, {3, 0}) = 0
20:13:24.112493 exit_group(0)           = ?
```

**Additional information**

I also tested the sigaction() function, and this is also not working! :(

Please help me, what can cause this issue. I don't know if this can be caused by an installed application, or library. I also asked some of my friends who are uses Ubuntu 14.04 to test it, and worked well.

How can I start the investigation of the root cause? The project is so huge to develop it on the server. So I need to use my PC instead of the server. I use Geany for development.

Please raise your question, or concern in the comments, and I try to answer it as soon as possible.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [USR1], 8) = 0`... Interesting. Why would `USR1` be blocked? Signal blocks are inherited, so perhaps you should check into whether something is blocking that for your shell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm pretty inexperienced in multi-threading, and signals. How can I start to check the possible blocks? I've checked and run the application with SUDO and this is working well. Maybe my normal account has no permission to send signals?

Comment: First check if the signal is blocked in the shell as well: `HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigBlk/{printf "0x%s", $2}' /proc/$$/status); for i in {0..31}; do (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); done | column`. This will print a list of signals currently blocked (if any).

Comment: I've found a reference in the kill() manpage:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/kill.2.html

The kernel 2.6-2.6.7 had a bug which dropped all signals with EPERM error. I'm going to check what you've advised.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 14.04 runs 3.13, which is a long way off from 2.6.7. (The given code works fine on my 14.04 system.)

Comment: @muru
`HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigBlk/{printf "0x%s", $2}' /proc/$$/status); for i in {0..31}; do (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); done | column`

and the result:

`10 USR1`

How can I unblock it?

Comment: Yep, my kernel version is 3.13.0-40-generic

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using Ubuntu GNOME (specifically, the GDM display manager) would you?

Comment: @muru: yes I use Ubuntu GNOME --- `gnome-shell --version` >>>>> `GNOME Shell 3.12.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're suffering from [this bug in GDM](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731228). The Debian package [3.12.2-4 has a fix](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756068). Looking at the GDM changelog for Ubuntu 14.04, it doesn't look like the fix was backported to 14.04, nor can I find a Launchpad bug report. So either:

1. Use another signal (only `SIGUSR1` was affected), or
2. Use another Display Manager (such as `lightdm`), or
3. Upgrade GDM (perhaps using the GNOME3 PPAs), or
4. Work in a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>), or
5. Explicitly unblock `SIGUSR1`, or
6. File a bug (`ubuntu-bug gdm`), and hope that the fix gets backported.

I'd advise you to do (1) and (6) for now.
At any rate, do (5) for any signal that you use.

Comment: I've found a bug patch, just I don't know how can I install it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731228#c7

Comment: @MontyX Unless you have a special affection for GDM, don't bother. The other options are simpler and easier.

Comment: I uses the SIGUSR2 instead of the SIGUSR1. This solved my issue. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it! :)